Leaking bathroom faucet handle - can't access cartridge to fix
My bathroom sink handle is leaking and I'm guessing the cartridge might need to be replaced. I cannot find any way to budge the bottom of the handle to get it out.
A little internet sleuthing and I think the faucet is a Kohler Forte Widespeead faucet, but I'm wondering if it was preinstalled in the vanity and maybe not meant to be removed. Is that a thing?
I've tried a valve wrench from underneath the sink as well as every kind of wrench from above. Admittedly, I'm not experienced, but it feels like it's fused to the cheap countertop. It's difficult to get any kind of grip from the top and I've already made marks on the base trying to grip it.
It's worth noting that the vanity is pretty crappy but I'm not looking to replace it right now. I just want my sink handle to not leak.





First pull out to the side the wire clip.
Then unscrew the bottom nut and the cartridge will come out (upwards)
There is noting you have to do from underneath the counter top.
